# Start mining without the need to downlod the 360gb blockchain

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, mining-theory, block

I am new to bitcoin mining but at least i understand the mathematics behind - the sha256 and finding nonce, i am a junior back-end developer. recently i have being interested in bitcoin mining, as way to earn revenue but spotted constraints that would hinder people from exploring the venture, all cost related. Which bring me to my question of how a solo-miner with the necessary requirements but with a less than 1.7mbps internet speed could evade the initial download of all the 360gb blockchain. it does seem like an eternity to wait for such a colossal download. and the reasons for such download is still unclear. it makes sense to only download the previous hashes, for the block you are trying to mine, but not the whole data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does bitcoin core need to download the blockchain](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38530/why-does-bitcoin-core-need-to-download-the-blockchain)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick No it actually doesn't i mean there are already verified blocks and are already in the chain and so i see no need to verify again, besides if one person verifies a block incorrectly it won't change the system, or will it?it is not practical to process every transaction that bitcoin has ever made to begin mining. There must/should be a way to skip all other blocks and maybe process the current block and the last few.

Comment: If you don't care about being deceived and having your money stolen then indeed you can dispense with security measures and simply trust random strangers. Its certainly a choice you can make.