# Why do I need to download the entire blockchain for a wallet when I can make one one with open source java like bitaddress.org

Tags: blockchain, wallet, synchronization, coldstorage

Like title said. And when i will have to use the btc I can login the wallet with the private key on a hot wallet.

Answer (score 2):

Downloading the blockchain makes it possible for your wallet to verify transactions and therefore protect you against some types of deception and theft. It is how Bitcoin achieves its inventor's main goal that one party can pay a second party **without any need for a trusted third party**.

Yes you can have separate cold and hot or watch-only wallets.

---

Related:

- [What kinds of wallets are there?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866)
- [Why does bitcoin core need to download the blockchain](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/38530/13866)